# Limits of $f(x)=x!\frac{e^{x}+1}{x^{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to say that I've no idea, but I just want to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\bigl(x!\dfrac{e^{x}+1}{x^{x}}\bigr)$

Comment: As written, the function has no dependence on $n$!

Comment: So is it a limit for $n$ or for $x$? It does not matter match for the result, but it matters for the methods that you're allowed to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Stirling approximation: $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n}$. Thus, $x! \frac{e^x+1}{x^x} \approx \sqrt{2\pi x} \frac{e^x+1}{e^x} \approx \sqrt{2\pi x}$ for large $x$. If you meant $e^{x+1}$ instead, you get $x! \frac{e^{x+1}}{x^x} \approx \sqrt{2\pi x} e$.

Answer (score -5):

The limit of $f(x)=x!\frac{e^{x}+1}{x^{x}}$ when $x\to\infty$ is $0$.

Comment: I don't think so: See the other answer, which gives an asymptotic representation that goes to infinity, and a quick numeric simulation also shows the expression increases.